# Define permission for a different usersets and role

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I use Server-to-server interaction feature of Google Drive using API to maintain files that are uploaded by a group of users and seen by others. Before I note down my problem let me first explain the structure of my app (in php).

I have multiple user groups. Let me explain them in brief:

1. User group 1 - Super Admin has the ability to upload/view/modify/download/delete a file in any folder.
2. User group 2 - Sub Admin has the ability to upload/view/modify/delete all files but only in a single folder.
3. User group 3 - Creator of content, they have the ability to upload/view files uploaded by them. Each creator has his own folder. (and has functionality to mark files to be downloaded)
4. User group 4 - Reader of content, they have the ability to view files uploaded by reader. (They will be able to download only certain files that the creator has marked for downloading, otherwise not.)

My App is live and functioning till now. And I need to add these functionalities but I couldn't find any specific documentation for these requirements.

1. How do I restrict files to open only through my website and not otherwise? No public links.
2. Disable download and other buttons on all files except for some (depending on the user type(id and role)).

Please provide me appropriate links or documentation regarding the same.

Comment: if you are uploading with a service account there is no web view no one can see the files access should only be via your application.   Again if the service account is controlling all of this there should be no download buttons.       Now if you are allowing people to open these files VIA their Google drive account that is your problem.   You wont be able to prevent them from editing it in google drive.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a service account. I let Creators upload files through a upload page and show those files on another. The Creators create post which is visible to specified readers along with the files attached with that post. But when the files are clicked they show a pop-out button and clicking that a new tab opens up with a whole lot of buttons. How do I confirm if is a service account? And restrict this setup?

Comment: So yes, it is a service account. I did some more digging and found that I can create multiple service accounts with role as owner, editor or viewer. Is this it or something else?